# I need to get my work_id in my header location

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to redirect my user to the site where he can see the jobs, after he did a insert.

```
 if(isset($_POST[godkend])) { 
      $pdo = Database::connect();  
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //write query
      $sql = "INSERT INTO godkend SET start = ?, job_art = ?, work_id = ?, nummer  = ?, work_done = ?"; 

    //prepare query for excecution
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //bind the parameters
    //this is the first question mark
      $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['start']); 
    //this is the second question mark
      $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['job_art']); 
    //this is the third question mark
      $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['work_id']); 
     //this is the fourth question mark
      $stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['nummer']);                
    // Execute the query
     $stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST['work_done']);  
       $stmt->execute();        


     $work_id = $_GET['work_id'];
      header("Location: web_opgaver.php?work_id='$_GET[work_id]'");     
      }
```

This is the part I am working on (above code will just give me a blank work_id

```
 header("Location: web_opgaver.php?work_id=$work_id");      
      }
```

and above here is the same, I tryed with post, get and 3-4 other things, but nothing works

Any help?

Comment: Do you need last inserted row id ?

Comment: If I understand you right, you can get the ID of the just-inserted row with `$pdo->lastInsertID()`

Comment: no, I need the work_iod form my user, if it is a painter, he will only se the jobs for painter, and if it is a plummer, he will only se the jobs for plummer (work_id) I know I have the work_id with me on the insert, cause it is in my db, so I can´t understand, why I cant use it in my location

Comment: what is your idea about `work_id from my user` ?! are you get work_id from `$_POST['work_id']` or `$_GET['work_id']`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$work_id = $_POST['work_id'];` as you have `$_POST['work_id']` in `$stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['work_id']);`

Comment: sean leave a answer, you where right, I did try it, but I had it inside ' ' but this worked
 header("Location: web_opgaver.php?work_id=$_POST[work_id]");